# How to do a forced-push to another branch in Git

Tags: git

Doing a forced push is done by:

```sh
git push origin +branch
```

Doing a push to a differently-named remote branch is done by:

```sh
git push origin local:remote
```

How does one do a forced push to a differently-named remote branch?

I tried:

```sh
git push origin local:+remote
```

But it creates a new branch named `+remote`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Some people are not reading [Jeff Puckett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36927977/1256452) first.  Do that!  This answer is about the use of the `+` force-push character, not about force-pushing in general.

---

Just to be a bit more complete than the accepted answer: the syntax for a refspec is `[+][src][:dst]`, with at most one of `src` and `:dst` being omitted (so that the empty string and `+` by itself are both invalid).

Hence the non-`--force` syntax for your case is `+local:remote`, rather than `local:+remote`.

Using `--force` has the effect of adding the `+` in front of every refspec, i.e., these two are equivalent:

```
git push --force origin someBranch local:remote anotherBranch
git push origin +someBranch +local:remote +anotherBranch
```

Comment: This is more in tune with my question. I will accept this instead.

Comment: Nice! what do `a` and `d` represent in your example?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: Just refspecs without a `:dst` part.  (You could use `+:dst` but there's no force action for deleting a refspec.)  A `:dst`-less refspec for `push` tells `push` to figure it out (there are long and complicated rules for this, due to having to stay compatible with all the historical mistakes :-) ).

Comment: @torek Can you edit it to be more clear? Maybe use remote and local instead of one-letter vars :)

Comment: @torek, wow, thanks, I knew about the `--all` option, but I didn't know that you could push 3 separate branches at once.

Comment: When I try to do this I get `error: src refspec local does not match any`. Am I supposed to replace "local" (and "remote") with something, and, if so, what?

Comment: @Dukeling: yes. `local` stands for the name of *your* branch and `remote` stands for the branch name you want to ask *their* Git to set in *their* repository. Remember, you have a Git repository, and it has branches—or rather, branch *names*—but those are *your* names. They have a Git repository, and it has branch names too, but those are *their* names. Just because you calls yours `master` and `develop` and so  on does not mean they have to use the same names. Maybe they call them `maestro` and `experiment`.

Comment: @torek Then I don't quite follow. I have a local branch A which I want to push to a remote branch B, so that's only 2 branches (or branch names). Where do the other 2 branch names come from?

Comment: @Dukeling: the example above is *an example*. When you run `git push`, you have your Git call up another Git and offer it commits. When your Git is done sending commits to their Git, your Git asks (regular push) or commands (force-push) them to set some of their branch names. The *left* side of a refspec selects a commit to send. The *right* side of a refspec selects *their* branch name you want to ask or tell them to set.

Comment: You *can* push *more than one* thing! You *do not have to* push more than one thing. The question was about the `+` sign in `+<src>:<dst>`. This sets the force flag for *that one thing*, which means you can selectively force-push to their branch B1 and non-force-push to their branch B2, in one `git push` command.

Answer (score 78):

The `+` needs to come at the beginning of the argument representing the couple.

```
git push origin +localBranchName:remoteBranchName
```

That's hard to remember sometimes, so there's also the `--force` flag.

```
git push origin --force localBranchName:remoteBranchName
```

But **be aware** if you push multiple branches with that flag, then they will *all* be force pushed.

```
git push origin --force localBranchName:remoteBranchName anotherLocalBranch
```

In that case, you may not have wanted to force push `anotherLocalBranch`, so you should instead use the `+` to specify which ones you want forced.

```
git push origin +localBranchNameForced:remoteBranchName localBranchNotForced:remoteBranchNotForced +anotherLocalBranchForcePushedToUpstreamTracking
```

Do read [Torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928149/4233593) for a better explanation, and check out some of his [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek?tab=answers&sort=votes) for world-class knowledge on git.